# After executing TestNG suite showing error 'java.lang.NullPointerException DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a hybrid framework in the Selenium webdriver with the Page Object Model(POM) and created 'TestBase.class' as a parent class.

Page object model contains the following pages :

Page objects & methods: 1. LoginPage.class and 2. LeadsPage.class

Page object model contains the following test cases file :

Test cases : 1. LoginPageTest 2. LeadsPageTest

TestBase.class

```
package com.core.qa.base;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.core.qa.config.PropertyFile;
import com.core.qa.utility.ExcelReading;
import com.core.qa.utility.Helper;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;

public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String browserName;
    public static String URL;

    public PropertyFile PropFile;
    public ExcelReading excelRead;

    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest logger;

    // TakeScreenshotEx ts = new TakeScreenshotEx();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() throws FileNotFoundException {  

        PropertyFile.readPropertiesFile();
        System.out.println("In before suite");      

        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardownMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            Helper.CaptureScreenshot(driver);
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

LeadsPage.class

```js
package com.sams.qa.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.core.qa.base.TestBase;

public class LeadsPage extends TestBase {
 
 //WebDriver driver;

 // Page factory OR Object repository

 @FindBy(id = "q_search")
 WebElement QuickSearchTxtBox;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"total_records\"]")
 WebElement totalNoOfLeads;

 @FindBy(linkText = "Leads")
 WebElement LeadsLink;

 @FindBy(id = "ui-id-1")
 WebElement LeadsListTab;

 @FindBy(id = "ui-id-2")
 WebElement LeadAssessmentTab;

 @FindBy(name = "addLead")
 WebElement AddLeadsBtn;

 @FindBy(name = "export")
 WebElement ExportAllLeadsbtn;

 @FindBy(name = "Search")
 WebElement FilterSearchBtn;

 @FindBy(name = "filter_search")
 WebElement SearchIDNametxtbox;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text()),'Assessment']")
 WebElement LeadsAssessmentTab;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text()),'Clear All']")
 WebElement ClearAllSrchFilter;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"tabs-1\"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]") 
 WebElement FirstLeadLink;

 @FindBy(name = "first_name")
 WebElement Fname;

 @FindBy(name = "last_name")
 WebElement Lname;

 @FindBy(name = "email")
 WebElement Email;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(text()),'Yes']")
 WebElement IsCustEmailYes;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(text()),'No']")
 WebElement IsCustEmailNo;

 @FindBy(name = "address1")
 WebElement Add1;

 @FindBy(name = "city")
 WebElement City;

 @FindBy(name = "zip_code")
 WebElement Zip;

 @FindBy(name = "azimuth")
 WebElement Azimuth;

 @FindBy(name = "phone")
 WebElement Phone;

 @FindBy(name = "lead_source_id")
 WebElement LeadSource;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//select[contains(text()),'PQRS']")
 WebElement LeadSrcvalue;

 @FindBy(name = "installer_id")
 WebElement Installerdrpdn;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='salesman_id']/option[2]")
 WebElement Salesman;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//select[contains(text()),'ABCD']")
 WebElement InstallerValue;

 @FindBy(id = "saveLead")
 WebElement SaveBtn;

 @FindBy(id = "startProposal")
 WebElement StartProposalBtn;

 @FindBy(name = "cancel")
 WebElement CancelBtn;

 // initializing page objects
 public LeadsPage(WebDriver ldriver) {  
  TestBase.driver = ldriver;
  PageFactory.initElements(ldriver, this);  
 }

 // Methods or Actions

 public LeadsPage openLeadspg() {
  LeadsLink.click();
  return new LeadsPage(driver);
 }
 
 public void openAssessmentTab()
 {
  LeadAssessmentTab.click();
 }
 
 public void leadsListtab()
 {
  LeadsListTab.click();
 }
 
 public String ValidateLeadsCurURL(WebDriver driver) {
  
  TestBase.driver=driver;
  return driver.getCurrentUrl();
 }

 public String GetLeadsCount() {
  return totalNoOfLeads.getText();
 }

 public String GetFirstLeadFrmList() {
  return FirstLeadLink.getText();

 }

 public void searchEditLead() {
  String FirstID = FirstLeadLink.getText();
  SearchIDNametxtbox.sendKeys(FirstID);
  FilterSearchBtn.click();
  ClearAllSrchFilter.click();

 }

 public void ValidateAddLeads(String fname, String lname, String email, String add1, String city, String zip,
   String phone) {
  Fname.sendKeys(fname);
  Lname.sendKeys(lname);
  Email.sendKeys(email);
  IsCustEmailYes.click();
  Add1.sendKeys(add1);
  City.sendKeys(city);
  Zip.sendKeys(zip);
  Phone.sendKeys(phone);
  SaveBtn.click();
 }

}
```

LeadsPageTest.class

```
package com.sams.qa.testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.core.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.core.qa.config.PropertyFile;
import com.sams.qa.pages.DashboardPage;
import com.sams.qa.pages.LeadsPage;
import com.sams.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class LeadsPageTest extends TestBase {

    LoginPage loginpg;
    DashboardPage dashboardpg;
    LeadsPage leadspage = new LeadsPage(driver);

    @Test(priority = 4, groups = "smoke")
    public void OpenLeadsPgTest() {

        System.out.println("In Open leads pg method");

        leadspage.openLeadspg();
        leadspage.openAssessmentTab();
        leadspage.leadsListtab();
        System.out.println("Leads count is :" + leadspage.GetLeadsCount());
    }

}
```

After executing testng.xml (suite) it gives below error for LeadsPageTest : -

```html
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.click(Unknown Source)
 at com.sams.qa.pages.LeadsPage.openLeadspg(LeadsPage.java:121)
 at com.sams.qa.testcases.LeadsPageTest.OpenLeadsPgTest(LeadsPageTest.java:31)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: `driver` in class `LeadsPageTest` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of changes i would suggest

1. init your elements in pageObject class, like this

   public LeadsPage(WebDriver driver) {
               this.driver = driver;
   pageFactory.initElements (driver, this);
           }

and delete pageFactory line from your test.

2. Try declaring your webdriver as static in your base class

   public static WebDriver driver;
3. Create object of pageobject class inside the test, like `LeadsPage leadspage = new Leadspage();`

Comment: thank you for your help and suggestions. I have implemented the same but still having the same issue. On LeadsPageTest SYSO msg get printed but not executing the next statement, LoginPageTest test cases are executing fine.

Comment: you could update your question with the new code, and also add the errors you get in console

Comment: Ok @Adrian, I have updated the changes as you suggested and also updated the new code and errors here, please check and advice.

Comment: public LeadsPage(WebDriver ldriver) {  
  TestBase.driver = ldriver;
  PageFactory.initElements(ldriver, this);  
 }
move this code before the FindBy tags, also change ldriver just for driver, and TestBase.driver for this.driver = driver
also in your test class, declare   LeadsPage leadspage = new LeadsPage(driver); inside your test not globally

Comment: these changes solved my problem and it works fine as expected, thank you so much.

Comment: could you please mark my answer as the one that resolved your issue? it helps me thanks